# Has anyone tried implementing a unsupported database to use for jobRepository for Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, hana

My database Sap Hana db is not supported for Spring Batch. I am looking for a guide on how to implement my own DAOs for SimpleJobRepository for SpringBatch. Has tried this before?

I did not include the database type property because according to spring batch website
not including it will auto search for a database type. I also used JobRepositoryFactoryBean
since the db is unsupported.

I am excited though to write my own implementation for this, maybe i can contribute it to
spring batch source.

My Setting is as follows:

```
   <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
        <property name="validateTransactionState" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

Currently I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/batch-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [HDB]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [HDB]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:79)
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Batch 3 offers the opportunity to inject custom database types.
Check [DatabaseType](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/support/DatabaseType.html) and [JobRepositoryFactotyBean.setDatabaseType()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setDatabaseType-java.lang.String-) (instead of let SB  autodetect database type from datasource).
Of course you need to create scripts for metadata tables creation (use [this](http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/spring-batch-hypersql-job-repository/) blog post for an example and [official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html))

Comment: can you please share the code snippet, it may help me in better understanding

Answer (score 2):

I manage to fix the problem above by implementing my own DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory and my own DatabaseType then I autowired the values to SimpleJobServerFactory.

Comment: Can you please explain how you did it?