# Spring batch --- DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to implement Spring Batch with Spring boot , since we are using informix database I'm running into the following exception when my spring boot App starts up.

configuration :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
   BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceProperties.getDbUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceProperties.getDbUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(dataSourceProperties.getDbPassword())
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource){

    DataSourceTransactionManager manager=new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    return manager;
}

@Bean
public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean( DataSourceTransactionManager txManager,DataSource dataSource ) throws Exception{

    JobRepositoryFactoryBean job=new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    job.setDataSource(dataSource);
    job.setDatabaseType("oracle");
    job.setTransactionManager(txManager);
    job.afterPropertiesSet();
    return job;
}


@Bean
public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor() {
    return new PersonItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    writer.afterPropertiesSet();
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener,JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean) throws Exception {


    return jobs.get("importUserJob")
             .repository(jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(s1)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Person> reader,
        ItemWriter<Person> writer, ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}
```

**Exception**

caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:79)
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.getDatabaseType(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer.initialize(BatchDatabaseInitializer.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)

Comment: do you have the library for the jdbc?  can you post your properties file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587674/has-anyone-tried-implementing-a-unsupported-database-to-use-for-jobrepository-fo

Comment: See this answer for how to do it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241229/using-spring-batch-with-auto-configure-and-a-non-standard-database/43259482#43259482](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241229/using-spring-batch-with-auto-configure-and-a-non-standard-database/43259482#43259482)

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch doesn't seem to directly support Informix.

From `org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType` :

```
DERBY("Apache Derby"), 
DB2("DB2"), 
DB2ZOS("DB2ZOS"), 
HSQL("HSQL Database Engine"),
SQLSERVER("Microsoft SQL Server"),
MYSQL("MySQL"),
ORACLE("Oracle"),
POSTGRES("PostgreSQL"),
SYBASE("Sybase"), H2("H2");
```

But, as was said here : http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/61097-why-spring-batch-doesn-t-support-informix-database, it seems you can set your database type to Oracle and it will support Informix.

Comment: Could you write how to set database type to Oracle? The link you provided is no longer live

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń There's an example in the question : `job.setDatabaseType("oracle");`