# DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-batch

While trying to setup a Spring boot - spring batch project, I am running into an error stating:

```
DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]
```

Full stack trace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.java.batch.processor.ProcessorApplication.main(ProcessorApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:117) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:82) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:121) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer.initialize(DefaultBatchConfigurer.java:111) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My properties setup is as follows:

```
impala.datasource.url={url inserted}
impala.datasource.username={Username}
impala.datasource.password={Password}
impala.datasource.driver-class-name=com.cloudera.impala.Driver
impala.datasource.threadNum=1
```

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone tried implementing a unsupported database to use for jobRepository for Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587674/has-anyone-tried-implementing-a-unsupported-database-to-use-for-jobrepository-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but Impala is currently not a [supported database type of Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/support/DatabaseType.html).
May be it is feasible for you to switch to one of the aforementioned database systems?

Alternatively you could try to register your own yet-unknown database like documented in the chapter [Non-standard Database Types in a Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) of the Spring Batch docs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @mle.. I'll look into manually registering