# how to fix the error "error creating bean with name...."

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when I run my application there is the following error displayed:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pamdaBatchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getJobRepository' defined in com.orange.pamda.config.PamdaBatchConfigurer: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'pamdaBatchConfigurer' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getJobRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [MariaDB]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

here is my file "pamdabatchconfigurer.java":

```
    package com.orange.pamda.config;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.orange.pamda.config.batch.listener.SendFileAfterExportListener;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.CatalogueExporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.CatalogueImporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.CommonJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.DataExporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.HierarchyValidatorJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.JobBuilderFactory;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.KoalaExporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.MappingExporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.MappingImporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.OrphanExporterJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.ReleaseJobConfiguration;
import com.orange.pamda.worker.config.SummaryExporterJobConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
@Import({ CommonJobConfiguration.class, CatalogueExporterJobConfiguration.class,
        CatalogueImporterJobConfiguration.class, DataExporterJobConfiguration.class,
        HierarchyValidatorJobConfiguration.class, KoalaExporterJobConfiguration.class,
        MappingExporterJobConfiguration.class, MappingImporterJobConfiguration.class,
        OrphanExporterJobConfiguration.class, ReleaseJobConfiguration.class, SummaryExporterJobConfiguration.class })
public class PamdaBatchConfigurer implements BatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        // jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(getTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    // @Bean
    // public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
    // SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new
    // SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    // simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(1000); // no throttle
    // return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    // }

    @Bean
    public JobBuilderFactory getJobBuilderFactory() throws Exception {
        return new JobBuilderFactory(getJobRepository(), sendFileAfterExportListener());
    }

    @Bean
    public StepBuilderFactory getStepBuilderFactory() throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilderFactory(getJobRepository(), transactionManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public SendFileAfterExportListener sendFileAfterExportListener() {
        return new SendFileAfterExportListener();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void init() throws Exception {
        JobExplorer jobExplorer = getJobExplorer();
        JobRepository jobRepository = getJobRepository();
        for (String jobName : jobExplorer.getJobNames()) {
            Set<JobExecution> runningJobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
            for (JobExecution runningJobExecution : runningJobExecutions) {
                runningJobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.UNKNOWN);
                runningJobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
                jobRepository.update(runningJobExecution);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I really do not know where this error comes from can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Most important part of the stacktrace: `DatabaseType not found for product name: [MariaDB]`

Look here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22344

Similar issues:

[DatabaseType not found for product name: [Impala]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230047/databasetype-not-found-for-product-name-impala)

[Spring batch --- DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622928/spring-batch-databasetype-not-found-for-product-name-informix-dynamic-serv)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this part of the exception, that you have added. It might be the reason : "Circular reference involving".

> Circular reference involving containing bean 'pamdaBatchConfigurer' -
>   consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
>   its containing instance.