# Why Spring batch doesn't support Informix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
    ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Informix Dynamic Server]
```

**Here spring DatabaseType class:**

```
public enum DatabaseType {

    DERBY("Apache Derby"),
    DB2("DB2"),
    DB2VSE("DB2VSE"),
    DB2ZOS("DB2ZOS"),
    DB2AS400("DB2AS400"),
    HSQL("HSQL Database Engine"),
    SQLSERVER("Microsoft SQL Server"),
    MYSQL("MySQL"),
    ORACLE("Oracle"),
    POSTGRES("PostgreSQL"),
    SYBASE("Sybase"),
    H2("H2"),
    SQLITE("SQLite");
```

**Any working example of work around will be appriciated?**

Comment: Apparently you can set it to Oracle, and that will work for Informix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622928/spring-batch-databasetype-not-found-for-product-name-informix-dynamic-serv?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo the link is not correct. and there is no explanation there.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/61097-why-spring-batch-doesn-t-support-informix-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone tried implementing a unsupported database to use for jobRepository for Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587674/has-anyone-tried-implementing-a-unsupported-database-to-use-for-jobrepository-fo)