# DatabaseType not found for product name: [Spark SQL]

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spring-batch, databricks

I am facing this issue while connecting Spring Batch with DataBricks.

Here's is how i am creating DataSource

```
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
   public DataSource dataSource(){
   DriverManagerDataSource source= new DriverManagerDataSource();
    source.setUrl("URL");
    source.setUsername("userName");
    source.setPassword("Password");
    source.setDriverClassName("com.simba.spark.jdbc41.Driver");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

This is how i am reading it in Spring Batch Item Reader

```
     JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    List<Employee> employeeData=  jdbcTemplate.query("select * from employee", new EmployeeMapper());
```

While i debugged further , i can see the "databaseProductName" as "Spark SQL" which is not supported in the list of available DataTypes in Spring batch

```
DERBY("Apache Derby"),
DB2("DB2"),
DB2VSE("DB2VSE"),
DB2ZOS("DB2ZOS"),
DB2AS400("DB2AS400"),
HSQL("HSQL Database Engine"),
SQLSERVER("Microsoft SQL Server"),
MYSQL("MySQL"),
ORACLE("Oracle"),
POSTGRES("PostgreSQL"),
SYBASE("Sybase"),
H2("H2"),
SQLITE("SQLite");
```

and i get this error DatabaseType not found for product name: [Spark SQL]

Comment: please post error that you have and code that you're using.

Comment: @AlexOtt I just added the information needed, does that help you.

Comment: I just added some more details, does that help you @AlexOtt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has anyone tried implementing a unsupported database to use for jobRepository for Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587674/has-anyone-tried-implementing-a-unsupported-database-to-use-for-jobrepository-fo)

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL is not supported by default. If you think one of the DDL scripts provided by Spring Batch is close enough to Spark SQL, you can set the database type using [JobRepositoryFactoryBean#setDatabaseType](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setDatabaseType-java.lang.String-).

Please check [Non-standard Database Types in a Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) for more details about the configuration of non standard job repositories.